# How to repair macOS home directory permission issues

Tags: macos

So, having trouble with AutoCAD LT on my Mac running macOS. The [Autodesk help site](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?id=18800510&linkID=15839490&siteID=123112) tells me to execute the following:

```
sudo chmod -R +w $HOME
```

And now Mail won't open, Safari is trapped behind a spinning beach ball of death, and ”Disk Utility -> Repair Permissions” hasn't helped.

Is there anyway to "undo" the `chmod` command?

Comment: Do you have a backup? Are you sure you executed that command? According to `history` run in Terminal, what did you really execute? While it's not a great advice from AutoDesk, there should be no downside to running it either.

Comment: history command doesn't return anything, and unfortunately I had some error with Time Machine and my external hard drive which I apparently never corrected....

Comment: @Marshall - Sure set the permissions to the directory to their original permissions.

Comment: adding permissions (specifically write) to everything in the home directory doesn't sound like it should break anything . . . removing might, depending on the permission, but adding things shouldn't?

Comment: I just noticed .bash_profile:Permission denied.  What's this?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l ~/`, specifically for .bash_profile. Whatever that is probably is the same issue for the rest, owned by root (meaning your user can't read it, depending on the perms of course).

Comment: I'm going to guess you had `-r` instead of `-R`, meaning you removed read permissions from your home directory, instead of recursively applying the change to the files in $HOME. . . @Nicholaz answer sounds like it'll work;  Note that after applying the chmod on $HOME, you'll likely want to re-apply the Autodesk fix

Comment: Don't use command line if you don't understand what you are typing.

Comment: @Sebf, good advice, just wish I had gotten it 2 hours ago...

Comment: Oouch, I missed the -R ... the command affected all files inside the user folder where you were logged in when you executed the sudo command.  But I agree with ernie's comment up there at the question, adding +w to all files should not be totally bad, not sure what problems it caused specifically though. But it will be very hard to revert that.  Can you look inside the users fold and compare with the other not affected?  e.g. ls -l /Users/User1/ vs. ls -l /Users/User2/ and compare the permissions of the folders which are common to both (e.g. Documents or Library)?

Comment: Basically, I can't open my desktop folder, Notes, Mail, etc. I tried sudo chmod 755 $HOME and sudo chmod 755 /User/anyuser both to no avail.  Am I going to have to haul this thing back to the Apple store? I thought I followed the syntax shown on the autodesk page perfectly, but apparently not...

Comment: So, for posterity, whatever I did I damaged my user profile beyond repair, and have to abandon it.  Last time I play in Terminal without a recent back up!

Answer (score 0):

The default permissions for the home path is 755

```
sudo chmod 755 $HOME
```

or

```
ls -l /Users
```

should give you something like `drwxr-xr-x`  for each user folder.

Then see which was changed then run the above `sudo chmod 755 /Users/baduser`

Comment: so I have: 
drwxr-xr-x+  11  Guest | 
drwxrwxrwt   11  root | 
drwxr-xr-x   46  User1 | 
drwxr-xr-x+  11  User2

how do I know which is bad?

Comment: Ignore this answer ... I did miss the -R in the original command.  The list you have looks okay, but -R does affect the files inside the folder, not the folder itself.  My bad.

Comment: What account were you using when running these commands?  (ie, what does `whoami` and `echo $HOME` output?  I'm a little concerned why is there a `/Users/root` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo cat ~/.bash_history` first to see if you actually ran just `sudo chmod -R +w $HOME`.

`sudo chmod -R +w $HOME` gives the user class write permission to all files and directories under ~/ recursively. That should normally be relatively harmless, because most files under ~/ are already writable by the user.

You could also try resetting home folder permissions:

- Restart and hold command-R after the screen turns on
- Open Terminal from the Utilities menu and run `resetpassword`
- Select the Macintosh HD volume and press the "Reset Home Folder Permissions and ACLs" button

Or if you have 10.6 or 10.5, start up from installation media and choose Reset Password from the Utilities menu.

Have you tried creating a new account? If everything works normally there, try just copying all directories except ~/Library/ from the old account.